# How can I process this file in C#?

Tags: c#, datagrid, text-parsing

I have a text file with **hundreds of entries** formatted like this, I need to display this file on a data grid, or other user friendly control "properly formatted" as per your advise. (my intention is to then export it to excel **not an optimal choice though** for further processing. all the columns are values in milliseconds so most of times these values are quite big up to 3 hrs, so I need to convert them into hours/minutes/seconds.) What is the best way to approach this task? Can this be done with the StreamReader? Can the conversion take place in code so there is no need to export to excel? Any samples? thank you!

```
  ENTRY DAY ENTRY TIME  IN.WORK   TEST %     TRY CORRER     CORTA   CICLO MAQUI
    O0.TXT            
      11/07/28  13:39:13        0        0     105       0       0       0       0
    O0.TXT            
      11/07/20  00:00:00        0        0   19145       0       0       0       0
    O0.TXT            
      11/07/19  15:04:10        0        0   32151       0       0       0       0
```

---

I want to format it as such:

```
FILE   ENTRY DAY ENTRY TIME  IN.WORK   TEST %   TRY    CORRER   CORTA   CICLO   MAQUI
O0.TXT 11/07/28  13:39:13        0        0     105       0       0       0       0
O0.TXT 11/07/20  00:00:00        0        0   19145       0       0       0       0
O0.TXT 11/07/19  15:04:10        0        0   32151       0       0       0       0
O0.TXT 11/07/07  05:22:40        0        0     508       0       0       0       0
```

---

I tried using the:

```
string fileName = "Myfile.txt";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
string[] delimiter = new string[] { " " };
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
     string[] lines = sr.ReadLine().Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
```

........

But I was not able to hold the format I wanted at all, nor to load it into a datagrid etc. for that matter.

Comment: maybe it's delimited by a tab (\t)?

Comment: if you want to use excel why don't you try converting this to csv by addings commas betweeen the column names and import it via excel?

Comment: Morpheus the excel part was because I could not figure a better way of processing the file, if it is possible I'd love to stay as far away as possible from excel. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string fileName = "Myfile.txt";

string[] delimiter = new string[] { " " };

List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();

string[] liens = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

foreach (string line in liens)
{
    rows.Add(line.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}

//Now if you want to display them each one row item separated by tab "`\t"` or csv `","`
string separator = "\t";

List<string> output = new List<string>();

foreach (string[] row in rows)
{
    output.Add(string.Join(separator, row));
}

string newFile = "result.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(newFile, output.ToArray());//save the output to new file.
```

Comment: What is the errors that you are getting? also what is the .net version you used?

Comment: Ok, Sorry I just didn't check the typos, However I fix it up and updated the answer, first `string[] row in rows` instead of `string row in rows`, second `string newFile` instead of `strgin newFile`, third `File.WriteAllLines(newFile, output.AotArray()`.

Comment: it worked no errors, I just have to figure out how to merge the two lines into one as indicated on the original request.

Comment: That what `string.Join` actually do, to merge array of string  call join like we did in the row here, example `string merged = string.Join( " ", line1, line2);` will merge the two lines separating them with `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

Is everything fixed? For example, is the date always 6 characters in and 8 characters long (or whatever the case may be)? If so I would split on "\r\n" as opposed to " ", and then process each line individually. You could do:

```
string fileName = "Myfile.txt";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
string[] delimiter = new string[] { "\r\n" };
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] lines = sr.ReadLine().Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    { 
        date = line.Substring(6, 8);
        // Do the other processing here.
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to come up with some logic for which lines you need to process.

Comment: @ pauleck1 yes the way ti looks here that is the way it comes out always